# Modifying my iframe css contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#iView').load( function () {
        $('this').contents().find("html").css("background-image","none");
    });
});



  <iframe src="http://l2-playcard.dnsalias.com:85/CRM/web/login.aspx" id="iView" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

My iframe background not change please help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Your use of an absolute URI implies that you are trying to access content on another domain.

This is impossible (baring the use of [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) combined with the co-operation of the site you are trying to access) for security reasons.